# Picking up a Sequence out of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sequence

I would like to find a way to pick the correct `"11"` out of my matrix.
You start from upper-left end, by `[1, 1]`, and move to the direction from left to right rowwise.

Each time you see the combination `"01"` or `"00"`, you should keep on moving from left to right till you find some `"11"`.

In the example 1 the correct solution would be the `"11"` on the position `[1, 3]`.

```
# Example 1:
(R) 

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   01   01   11
# [2,]   11   01   11
# [3,]   01   11   10
```

Once you have a `"10"` you must change the line and start from the second line.
In the example 2 the code must end up with the result `"11"` on the `[2, 1]` position.

```
# Example 2:
(R1)

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   01   10   11
# [2,]   11   01   11
# [3,]   01   11   10
```

The command below would work for the second example, but not for the first one.

```
which(R == "11",  arr.ind = T)
```

I am looking for the position of the correct `"11"` in the matrix. Any idea would be highly appreciated!

p.s. 
For replication of R and R1:

```
R <- structure(c("01", "11", "01", "01", "01", "11", "11", "11", "10"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
R1 <- structure(c("01", "11", "01", "10", "01", "11", "11", "11", "10"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
```

Comment: I don't understand what your expected output is.

Comment: The position of correct "11" in the matrix.

Comment: @And_R your second example doesnt work with your first one. Can you explain how the correct answer is [2, 1] in example 2 since it was not preceded by "01" and "00"

Comment: @loki for the matrix R the desired output is c(1,3), for the R1: c(2,1)

Comment: @Taran look you start by [1, 1] in example 2, it is "01", you move on to the second value rowwise, it is "10" on the position [1, 2]. As it is 10, you jump to the next line and start with the first element [2, 1]. This one is "11", so you found the correct "11". The code should print c(2,1) as a desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another little function that does it for you:

```
foo <- function(mat, a, b) {
  res <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) replace(x, cumsum(x == a) > 0, NA)))
  res <- which(res == b, arr.ind = TRUE)
  res[order(res[,1], res[,2]),][1,]
}

foo(R, "10", "11")
#row col 
#  1   3 
foo(R1, "10", "11")
#row col 
#  2   1
```

This works by-row and replaces any elements after a "10" with NA and then gets the first "11" occurence.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple function that does what you want. Parameters are the matrix `m`, the string you are searching for `strSearch` (here "11") and the string that stops the search on a given row `strStop` (here "10").

The loops work through each row and column, breaking when the stop string is found, and returning at the first instance of the search string. The returned vector of length two contains the row and column indices.

If the search string is not found, `NA` is returned.

```
R <- structure(c("01", "11", "01", "01", "01", "11", "11", "11", "10"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
R1 <- structure(c("01", "11", "01", "10", "01", "11", "11", "11", "10"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))

getPosition <- function(m, strSearch, strStop) {

  for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(m))) {
      if (m[i, j] == strStop) break
      if (m[i, j] == strSearch) return(c(i, j))
    }
  }

  return(NA)
}
```

Sample output:

```
> getPosition(R, "11", "10")
[1] 1 3
> getPosition(R1, "11", "10")
[1] 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
find_index <- function(matr) {
  # find the col index of first "10" in each row 
  ind10 <- apply(matr, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x == "10") == 0, 
                 length(x) + 1, min(seq_len(length(x))[x == "10"])))
  # find the col index of first "11" in each row 
  ind11 <- apply(matr, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x == "11") == 0, 
                 length(x) + 1, min(seq_len(length(x))[x == "11"])))

  # check if 11 is before 10
  ind <- ifelse(ind10 < ind11, NA, ind11)

  # select the first row where "11" is before "10"
  rownumber <- which(!is.na(ind))[1]
  # and its colnumber
  colnumber <- ind[rownumber]
  return(c(rownumber, colnumber))
}
find_index(R)
find_index(R1)
```

Then the output is like this.

```
> find_index(R)
[1] 1 3
> find_index(R1)
[1] 2 1
>
```

Since you didn't specify that what happens if there is an entry other than "11", "01", "10", "00" I ignore the possibility.

**EDIT**
Since it was complicated to read, I created a bit more readable version with text concatenation.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

find_11_before_10 <- function(x){
  text <- x %>% paste(collapse = "|") 
  if(stri_detect_fixed(text, "11") &
     stri_detect_regex(text, "10.+11", negate = T)){
    return(which(x == "11") %>% min)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

find_index2 <- function(matr){
  ind <- apply(matr, 1, find_11_before_10)
  rownumber <- which(!is.na(ind))[1]
  colnumber <- ind[rownumber]
  return(c(rownumber, colnumber))
}

find_index2(R)
find_index2(R1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches.

**1) regular expression** Collapse `t(m)` into a single space-separated string and use `strapply` with the indicated regular expression to pick out everything from the beginning of that string to the first 11 that follows a 00 or 01.  The number of spaces plus 1 in the extracted string is the position of the 11. Convert that to row and column numbers.

```
library(gsubfn)

v <- paste(t(m), collapse = " ")
ix <- head(strapply(v, ".*?0[01].*?11", ~ nchar(gsub("\\S", "", x)), simplify = c), 1) + 1
c(t(row(m))[ix], t(col(m))[ix])
## [1] 1 3
```

**2) Position/Find** A different approach calculates the position of the first 00 or 01, `w0`, and `ix`, the position of the first 11 greater than `w0`. Finally 
compute the row and column numbers.

```
w0 <- Position(isTRUE, grepl("0[01]", t(m)))
ix <- Find(function(x) x > w0, which(t(m) == 11))
c(t(row(m))[ix], t(col(m))[ix])
    ## [1] 1 3
```

**3) state machine** Using switch and Reduce we could implement a state machine.  We are in state 1 starting out.  As soon as we find a 00 or 01 we transition to state 2 and when in state 2 upon finding a 11 we transition into state 3.  If we are in state 3 or 4 we transition into state 4.  State 3 is the position of the first 11 after a 00 or 01.

```
transition <- function(state, x)
  switch(state,
    if (x == "00" || x == "01") 2 else 1,
    if (x == "11") 3 else 2,
    4,
    4)
r <- Reduce(transition, init = 1, c(t(m)), accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
ix <- which(r == 3)
c(t(row(m))[ix], t(col(m))[ix])
## [1] 1 3
```

**Note:** We used this as the input:

```
m <- structure(c("01", "11", "01", "01", "01", "11", "11", "11", "10"
), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```